# Is there an equivalent of the erase-remove idiom in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, erase-remove-idiom

If I add or delete an element while iterating over an Array or an Array-like object in Javascript, do I need to take into account that the underlying collection may have changed or that the iterators may have become invalidated? In other words, is there an equivalent to the [Erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) for C++ in Javascript?

Comment: Usually, JavaScript is used in a functional fashion. It means that you are likely to use the `filter` method before `map` or `forEach`

Comment: By the way, yes you may need to take into account that your "next element" isn't what you expect, if you modify the array while iterating. But this doesn't happen in functional programming since it's everything immutable.

Comment: I think these two comments answer my question. If you post an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There's no equivalent because JS has garbage collection, i.e., you don't need to call `erase` on the tail after calling the equivalent of remove.

You can delete from an array while iterating.